# error: web driver object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm using selenium with chromedriver, and getting an error when trying to interact with a specific element.

HTML class code:
`<div class="label-31sIdr">Fresh</div>`

Selenium Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time

path = '/Users/stryker/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

payload = {
    'content': "pls pm"
}

header = {
    'authorization': 'xxxxx'
}

for i in range (1000):
    r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/991579455376072775/messages', data=payload, headers=header)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Fresh')
    button.click()
    time.sleep(30)
```

This is the error:

```
     line 19, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Fresh')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'
```

Comment: You have not open browser by selenium, use `driver.get(url)` to open the page you want to click `Fresh` button.

And class name is `label-31sIdr`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium just removed that method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, THE_CLASS_NAME)
```

Or without the extra import:

```py
driver.find_element("class name", THE_CLASS_NAME)
```

For improved reliability, you should consider using `WebDriverWait` in combination with `element_to_be_clickable`.

The other issue is that you mentioned the HTML is:
`<div class="label-31sIdr">Fresh</div>`
but you are trying to use `Fresh` as the class name when `label-31sIdr` is the class name. The code for that would be:

```py
driver.find_element("class name", "label-31sIdr")
```

Comment: I didn't know about that update so, thank you Michael for the info but the reason i was using `Fresh` was cuz there are 4 classes and all name "label-31sIdr" only the name between div is different